# How can I determine parent record of file uploaded through related list of notes and attachment?

Tags: files, content, parent

I have uploaded a file to Notes and Attachment section and I expect ParentId field on ContentDocument record to be populated with the actual Opportunity record Id where I have uploaded this record but it is actually empty.

I am trying to execute the following SOQL query

```
SELECT ID, ContentDocument.ParentId FROM ContentVersion
```

but every parent id is blank.

How can I find out who is the parent record of the file if I know that file was uploaded in the one of Notes and Attachments related lists on any of standard or custom objects?

Comment: for ContentVersion it is `FirstPublishLocationId` and not a ParentId

Comment: well, when I query for FirstPublishLocationId, this either returns blank or user id, while I have attached the file to the opportunity

Answer (score 1):

We need to query `ContentDocumentLink` object like following

```
SELECT Id, LinkedEntity.Name FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE ContentDocumentId IN ('0690600000YVxHJ', '0690600000YVxIR', '0690600000YVxJj', '0690600000YVxJj')
```

However, it doesn't support inner subqueries, so the following option would fail

```
SELECT Id, LinkedEntity.Name FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE ContentDocumentId IN (SELECT Id FROM ContentDocument)
```

Instead we need to query Ids of files we are interested in

```
Set<Id> ids = new Map<Id, ContentDocument>([SELECT Id FROM ContentDocument]).keyset();
```

and then use it for the next query

```
List<ContentDocumentLink> link = [SELECT Id, LinkedEntityId, LinkedEntity.Name FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE ContentDocumentId IN :ids];
```

Also, `ParentId` field is not about record ownership but about library ownership

> ID of the library that owns the document. Created automatically when
> inserting a ContentVersion via the API for the first time.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_contentdocument.htm

Comment: `ketset` => `keySet`

Comment: thanks @kurunve